# I'm struggling to write test cases for below code (Karma + Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am struggeling to write a test cases in karma and jasmine for below code. So please provide valid test case for beloe code. Thanks in advance.

```js
     angular.module('formlyApp').factory('commonService', ['$http', '$q', 'SessionService', 'Constants', '$stateParams', commonService]);
    
        
        function commonService($http, $q, SessionService, Constants, $stateParams) {
        var commonService = {};
        var configData = {};
        
        //Getter to access page object in config file
          commonService.getfunctionLinkObject = function(functionLink) {
           var returnObj = {};
           if(functionLink && functionLink != '') {
            angular.forEach(commonService.getConfigData(), function(value, key) {
             if(value.pageName == commonService.getPageName() && value.panelName == functionLink) {
              returnObj = value;
             }
            });
           }
           return returnObj;
          };
        
        }
        })();
```